# How To Open a File with t2s extension

Tags: file-extension

I have been searching to find out more about a file with a *t2s* file extension, but have not found a lot of information about it.

Our electric utility, Eversource, sent someone in town (town employee) a file with a t2s file extension.

What software opens a file with this extension?

Comment: If you're on a linux machine you can run `file filename.t2s` on it to get more information. Extensions are really meaningless, there is hex data at the start and end of a file that truly designates what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a reach, but a quick search for that file type appears to indicate that it is called a Tier 2 Submit file and is related in some manner to the US Environmental Protection Agency. If this is consistent with your understanding of the context of the file, there's a [document here](https://www.epa.gov/epcra/tier2-submit-software) that may be of some value.

> EPA developed Tier2 Submit to help facilities prepare an electronic
>   chemical inventory report.

The link includes references to software to be downloaded and installed to create the necessary file structure. Reference is also made to import and export, implying that one might be able to read an existing T2S file.

The linked location also references "reporting requirements for your state," linking to what is a list of states, parameters and contact information for each state.